# How do Angular 2 tests pass despite a compile error?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner

I've created a brand new Angular 2 app using `ng new` (`@angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.31`).

I changed just one line to create a compile-time error:

```
// src/app/app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: number = 'app works!';
}
```

`npm start` errors out as expected:

```
ERROR in /Users/administrator/Workspaces/Scratch/test-app/src/app/app.component.ts (9,3): Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.)
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Yet `npm test` continues to show 3 successful tests:

```
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.254 secs / 0.25 secs)
```

How is this possible? Is there a recommended way to ensure tests fail if there's a compile error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the rebuild failed, the old transpiled files are probably still present and the tests are likely running against those.

Comment: Thanks, but it does appear to recompile. When I add `const foo: number = 'bar';` to the top of the file, I'm able to see that in the resulting built file: `var foo = 'bar';` (via Chrome Sources).